# Passing variable in onclick: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected indentifier

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to pass an object to a function in the onclick event. If I run the code below, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected indentifier`. If I uncomment the `JSON.stringify` line, and use `taskAsJson` in place of `task`, I get the same error.

```
$.each(tasks, function (index, task) {
    //var taskAsJson = JSON.stringify(task);
    items.push('<li><a href="#" onclick="showTask(' + task + ');">' + task.Description + '</a></li>');
});
```

However, if I hard-code a value, like 5, it works and 5 gets passed to the function.

```
$.each(tasks, function (index, task) {
    items.push('<li><a href="#" onclick="showTask(' + 5 + ');">' + task.Description + '</a></li>');
});
```

Why do I get that error when I try to pass my object? What do I need to change in order to be able to pass `task` or `taskAsJson`?

Note: items is an array that gets used to update a div and listview:

```
$('#appTasks').append(items).listview('refresh');
```

Comment: Did you actually use `taskAsJson` in your code? When you write `'...' + task + '...'`, i.e. performing string concatenation, then the object `task` will be converted to a string. The default string representation of an object is `[object Object]`, which in your case leads to the string `<a href="#" onclick="showTask([object Object]);">`. This doesn't look like proper JS, does it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript in HTML is bad. HTML in JavaScript is bad. JavaScript in HTML in JavaScript? You get problems like these.

Make the element the right way.

```
var items = $.map(tasks, function(task) {
    return $('<li>').append(
        $('<a>', {
            href: '#',
            text: task.Description,
            click: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                showTask(task);
            }
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: +1 for the tips. I tried this and now each `<li>` in my listview is blank. And when `showTask()` receives a `task`, `task.Description` shows as undefined. I'm trying to work through it...

Comment: @BobHorn: My bad — got the argument order to `$.map` backwards :) It should be fixed now.

Comment: I was just about to edit your answer because I found that same issue here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `showTask(' + task + ');` lacks quotes inside the JavaScript code. For example, if `task` would be "cars" the HTML created will be `onclick="showTask(cars)"`. Now "cars" lacks quotes. In addition, in your example `task` probably isn't even a string but an object, so you are looking for something like `task.id` to get the right parameter. Otherwise `task`'s string representation will be `[object Object]`.

It works when you hardcode 5 because 5 is a number value that does not require quotes. (`onclick="showTask(5)"` is valid)

So if you change it to `showTask(\'' + task + '\');` it should work because the escaped \' will be ' in the final HTML code leading to `onclick="showTask('valueOfTask')"` (at least if `task` is the string you want in the parameter). But, as minitech pointed out, it's generally bad to put JS code in HTML.

Comment: +1 for the tip. Thank you. Couldn't get it to work, so I'm trying the other answer at the moment.